# exception while installing My SQL server for windows 7?

Tags: mysql

i downloaded the recommend version from [Download MySQL Community Server](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) i.e mysql-installer-community-5.6.12.0.msi for windows 7 64 bit os.

> Please install the .NET framework 4. Please install the .NET framework
>   then run this installer.

My question is  Should i really install .net 4 framework first to install mysql server? Am i proceeding in right direction

Comment: Yes, install and be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard installer includes MySQL Workbench. If you look at its [download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/), and in the pre-requisites:

> To be able to install and run MySQL Workbench 5.2 your System needs to have libraries listed below installed. The listed items are provided as links to the corresponding download pages where you can fetch the necessary files.
>
> - [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17113)
> - [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555)

So, yes.

(There may be other packages that also depend on .NET. Workbench was the obvious one I know of)

Comment: yes your are right. I should have checked pre-requisites first

Comment: @emilly - not really your fault - it's easy(ish) to find pre-requisites on individual components, not so easy to find them for the single integrated package.